# Need modification to regex to work in other situations

Tags: python, regex

Just discovered that the structure of my file could be different and my regex only works sometimes because of this change. My regex is
    `v6 = re.findall(r'(?s)----------\s*LOW VOLTAGE SUMMARY BY AREA.*?\rACTIVITY.+?',wholefile)`

It currently matches the following section of the file.

```
----------           LOW VOLTAGE SUMMARY BY AREA            ----------

         BUS   NAME   BASKV    VOLT    TIME       AREA     ZONE

       12006  [AMISTAD 69.0]   0.971   1.8700  10 NEW MEXICO    121
       11223  [WHITESA213.8]   0.918   1.9900  11 EL PASO       110
       70044  [B.HYDROB4.16]   0.955   2.3233  70 PSCOLORADO    703
       70044  [B.HYDROB4.16]   0.955   2.3233  70 PSCOLORADO    703
       79086  [PAGOSA   115]   0.937   2.0333  73 WAPA R.M.     791

ACTIVITY? 
PDEV

ENTER OUTPUT DEVICE CODE:
 0 FOR NO OUTPUT
 1 FOR PROGRESS WINDOW
```

However that section of the file sometimes is as below

```
    ----------           LOW VOLTAGE SUMMARY BY AREA            ----------

         BUS   NAME   BASKV    VOLT    TIME       AREA     ZONE

       12006  [AMISTAD 69.0]   0.742  13.2060  10 NEW MEXICO    121
       11223  [WHITESA213.8]   0.916   1.8367  11 EL PASO       110
       70187  [FTGARLND69.0]   0.936  19.6099  70 PSCOLORADO    710
       73216  [WINDRIVR 115]   0.858   3.6100  73 WAPA R.M.     750

(VFSCAN) AT TIME = 20.0000 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW FREQUENCY BELOW 59.600:

X ----- BUS ------ X    FREQ       X ----- BUS ------ X    FREQ
12063 [ROSEBUD 13.8]   59.506
```

On both occasions I would like to capture just the section below:

```
----------           LOW VOLTAGE SUMMARY BY AREA            ----------

     BUS   NAME   BASKV    VOLT    TIME       AREA     ZONE

   12006  [AMISTAD 69.0]   0.971   1.8700  10 NEW MEXICO    121
   11223  [WHITESA213.8]   0.918   1.9900  11 EL PASO       110
   70044  [B.HYDROB4.16]   0.955   2.3233  70 PSCOLORADO    703
   70044  [B.HYDROB4.16]   0.955   2.3233  70 PSCOLORADO    703
   79086  [PAGOSA   115]   0.937   2.0333  73 WAPA R.M.     791
```

How can my regex return the section above regardless of which version of the file I am lookin at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
v6 = re.findall(r'(?s)----------\s*LOW VOLTAGE SUMMARY BY AREA.*?\r(ACTIVITY|\(VFSCAN\)).+?',wholefile)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and let you know.

Comment: I am trying this but it appears that my original regex was giving me more than I wanted but I did not notice it until now. What I had before was grabbing everything to the end of the file, since this match occurs near the end of the file I did not notice that it was not working. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think that the problem probably is the last part: `.+?` Is matching to the end of the file. You can try:
`v6 = re.findall(r'(?s)----------\s*LOW VOLTAGE SUMMARY BY AREA.*?\r(ACTIVITY|\(VFSCAN\)).*?[:?]',wholefile)`

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Travelling for the next couple of days so will respond on the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest to use a regex, but do some parsing instead. Let's assume your data is in a string called `data`:

```
lines = [line for line in data.split("\n")]

# find start of header
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if "LOW VOLTAGE SUMMARY BY AREA" in line:
        start_index = index
        break

# first first data entry (line starting with whitespace and then a number)
for index, line in enumerate(lines[start_index:]):
    if line.strip() and line.split()[0].isdigit():
        first_entry_index = start_index + index
        break

# find last data entry (line starting with whitespace and then a number)
for index, line in enumerate(lines[first_entry_index:]):
    # we don't do this inside the if because it's possible
    # to end the data with only entries and whitespace
    end_entry_index = first_entry_index + index

    if line.strip() and not line.split()[0].isdigit():
        break

# print all lines between header and last data entry
print("\n".join(lines[start_index:end_entry_index]))
```

Comment: I really like this answer but I will have to try it to see how slow or how fast it is in relation to my current method. I may end up using both the regex and the parse. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Really appreciated!

Comment: Instead of printing, how would I get the lines with the numbert into a list that I may work with. The header information is just to identify the section of interest. I really just want the lines starting with the numbers. This file may be as large as 80 Mb

Comment: @user1642486: `lines[start_index:end_entry_index]` is exactly what you described.

Comment: Great. Again thanks for laying this out so that even I could understand.

Comment: After the crunch I will change my code to do this. Thanks again.